# How to add css in Vue-Toasted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-toasted

I am trying to add the following css, but it isn't working. I think I am going according to the documentation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toasted

None of the following approaches work.

The function being used @click of a div.

```
showToast(){
   this.$toasted.show('Email Sent!',{
        position: "top-right", 
        duration : 5000,
        class: 'toasting'
      });
```

OR

```
showToast(){
   this.$toasted.show('Email Sent!',{
        position: "top-right", 
        duration : 5000,
        className: ['toasting']
      });
```

Style

```
.toasting {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: pink;

}
```

Comment: did you `Vue.use(Toasted)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default CSS should be overridden by your CSS. SO your need to use `!important` in your CSS. Here is the css :

```
<style>
.toasting {
  color: yellow !important;
  background-color: pink !important;
}
</style>
```

Working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-toasted-example-forked-hd4n3?file=/App.vue)

Comment: Hey, even though its working in the fiddle. It's not working in my project for some reason.

Comment: inspect the css applied rules into the devtool

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same issue, the solution above works but keep in mind it's only **without** style scoping!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33065193)